# How Enabling Ordering key in cloud pub/sub messages works as i am facing an issue while trying to access those messages in batch

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp, spring-cloud-gcp

Enabling ordering key in cloud pubsub message is not working as expected like when we have same ordering key for multiple messages in topic it will process the messages sequentially one by one in an order but when we have different ordering key for each message in topic, it will collect all the messages in batch and process those in any random order.

How to process messages in batches having ordering key sequentially.

I tried to process messages having same ordering key and different ordering key but they are not working as expected. I want to process those messages in sequential order using ordering key and in batches.

Comment: Can you share how you publish the message, and your PubSub configuration?